# Python Pandas resample, odd behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 datasets (cex2.txt and cex3) wich I would like to resample in pandas. With one dataset I get the expected output, with the other not.
The datasets are tick data and are exactly equally formatted. Actually, the 2 datasets are only from two different days.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

pd.set_option ('display.mpl_style', 'default')


time_converter = lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x))
data_frame = pd.read_csv('cex2.txt', sep=';', converters={'time': time_converter})

data_frame.drop('Unnamed: 7', axis=1, inplace=True)
data_frame.drop('low', axis=1, inplace=True)
data_frame.drop('high', axis=1, inplace=True)
data_frame.drop('last', axis=1, inplace=True)

data_frame = data_frame.reindex_axis(['time', 'ask', 'bid', 'vol'], axis=1)

data_frame.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data_frame['time']), inplace=True)

ask = data_frame['ask'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')
bid = data_frame['bid'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')
vol = data_frame['vol'].resample('15Min', how='sum')

print ask
```

from the cex2.txt dataset I get this wrong output:

```
                      open  high  low  close
1970-01-01 01:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 01:15:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 01:30:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 01:45:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 02:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 02:15:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 02:30:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 02:45:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 03:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1970-01-01 03:15:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
```

from the cex3.txt dataset I get correct values:

```
                         open      high       low     close
2014-08-10 13:30:00  0.003483  0.003500  0.003483  0.003485
2014-08-10 13:45:00  0.003485  0.003570  0.003467  0.003471
2014-08-10 14:00:00  0.003471  0.003500  0.003470  0.003494
2014-08-10 14:15:00  0.003494  0.003500  0.003493  0.003498
2014-08-10 14:30:00  0.003498  0.003549  0.003498  0.003500
2014-08-10 14:45:00  0.003500  0.003533  0.003487  0.003533
2014-08-10 15:00:00  0.003533  0.003600  0.003520  0.003587
```

I'm really at my wits' end. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Edit:
Here are the data sources:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14055520/cex2.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14055520/cex3.txt
Thanks!

Comment: Trying checking what datatypes are contained in the dataframe before the resampling takes place. data_frame.dypes

Comment: Just checked it, both times exactly the same datatyps in it.

Comment: A somewhat common issue is that there is one row that contains a string or something that is not numeric. Or that one file has headers, and the other does not. Double check there is not some junk in one of the columns causing the issues. Normally printing the dypes will let you know pretty quickly, though not always.

Comment: If you can make a small, reproducible example that other people can copy and paste it would make it much easier to track down the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I already prepared the data to post, but forgot ;)

Comment: When I loaded cex2, there's a row whose date is 1969-12-31 18:00:00.003500. Looks like an error since nearly every other row is from the last couple of days.. Thus, the resample will try to fill in between the junk date, to current- and you'll see errors. You have a junk line somewhere in your data.

Comment: Yep, the line `0.00351055;1407627785;0.0035;0.00325064;88029.42722427;` looks broken.  (It's worth noting that you probably would have noticed this yourself while trying to find a minimal reproducing example. :^)

Comment: https://twitter.com/BigDataBorat/status/306596352991830016

Comment: oh that's embarrissing - it was late yesterday... I should have looked better at my data, anyways thanks a lot for you help!